# Team Fortress 2 fails to launch with primus/optirun

Tags: nvidia, games, nvidia-optimus, steam, bumblebee

Few days ago I installed Steam, TF2, bumblebee and the newest nvidia drivers. My laptop has an integrated intel gpu and dedicated card (geforce 645m).

I used to launch steam using `primusrun steam` and just launch TF2 from the steam menu. Everything worked fine and linux used the dedicated gpu for the game giving me stable 100fps.

Without (seemingly) changing anything, today I started having problems: the game won't launch. It doesn't give any errors, just the "Preparing to launch" screen and then it simply disappears. I can still run steam using primus/optirun without problems.

I tried launching steam without primus/optirun and insert `primusrun %command%` to launch options but it didn't work. The game plays just fine without primus/optirun, but the framerate is quite terrible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer to my own question here: https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/3506